# What is this little red schematic symbol?

Tags: usb, schematics, symbol

In the schematic screenshot below (from example 1 [here](https://www.acmesystems.it/pcb_usb#)), there is a little red symbol on some of the lines - e.g., where the big red arrow is pointing:

[image: illustration of mysterious schematic symbol]

[Here’s another](https://www.acmesystems.it/www/roadrunner/Berta_D2_schematic.pdf) online schematic where the same symbol is used.

I can't figure out what the red symbol means.  My best guess is that its some EDA program’s net class indicator, because they seem to come in pairs, but I’m really not sure.  Does anyone know if this red symbol means anything?

(Tagged `usb` because I've only seen this in USB-related schematics, but that might just be a function of what I tend to browse for.)

Comment: BTW that schematic looks like altium to me.

Comment: [Interactively Routing a Differential Pair on a PCB in Altium Designer](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/interactively-routing-differential-pairs-pcb)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It indicates that the signal is part of a differential pair.

Comment: This makes complete sense and explains why I keep seeing it in USB circuits.  Thank you.

Comment: Worth pointing out that it is depicting two waveforms with opposite polarity, similar to what differential signal looks like usually.